# Either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, average

I used the following query:

```
select Patients.LastName, 
  avg (PatientVisits.Pulse)as pulse,
  avg (patientvisits.depressionlevel)as depressionLevel  
from Patients 
left join PatientVisits 
   on Patients.PatientKey=PatientVisits.PatientKey
```

But I get the following error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'Patients.LastName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add a `GROUP BY` to your query:

```
select Patients.LastName, 
   avg (PatientVisits.Pulse)as pulse,
   avg (patientvisits.depressionlevel)as depressionLevel  
from Patients 
left join PatientVisits 
  on Patients.PatientKey=PatientVisits.PatientKey 
GROUP BY Patients.LastName
```

SQL Server requires any columns in your `SELECT` list that are not in an aggregate function be included in a `GROUP BY`.  Since you are trying to return the `Patients.LastName` while you are aggregating the data you must include that column in a group by.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. I can't believe I was missing something so simple.