# Column 'city.POPULATION' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

I was creating a query, and i saw this error-message.
This is the query i'm trying to execute:

```
select D.ID_city
,      D.ID_year
,      D.NB_deaths
,      D.NB_births_M
,      D.NB_births_F
,      D.NB_population_AS
,      D.NB_population_ACL
,      COUNT( NB_births_M+ NB_births_F)/C.population as  Birthrate
,      COUNT(NB_deaths_M + NB_deaths_F) as Mortality
from   Demography D 
join   region C
on     (D.Id_city =C.Id_city)
group
by     D.ID_city
,      D.ID_year
,      D.NB_deaths_M
,      D.NB_births_M
,      D.NB_births_F
,      D.NB_population_AS
,      D.NB_population_ACL
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @user2315555: The title...

Comment: Have you considered adding the Column 'city.POPULATION' to the group by clause? Or removing it from the select list? The error seems fairly self explanatory....

Comment: D.NB_deaths_F,c.population --> add in group by

Comment: possible duplicate of [Either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492994/either-an-aggregate-function-or-the-group-by-clause)

Answer (score 0):

You should include `c.population` in the `group by`, since you use that column outside the `count` aggregate function:

```
COUNT( NB_births_M+ NB_births_F)/C.population
```

Use this (added `D.NB_deaths_F` too since it is necessary too):

```
select D.ID_city
,      D.ID_year
,      D.NB_deaths
,      D.NB_births_M
,      D.NB_births_F
,      D.NB_population_AS
,      D.NB_population_ACL
,      COUNT( NB_births_M+ NB_births_F)/C.population as  Birthrate
,      COUNT(NB_deaths_M + NB_deaths_F) as Mortality
from   Demography D 
join   region C
on     (D.Id_city =C.Id_city)
group
by     D.ID_city
,      D.ID_year
,      D.NB_deaths_M
,      D.NB_deaths_F -- <-- added
,      D.NB_births_M
,      D.NB_births_F
,      D.NB_population_AS
,      D.NB_population_ACL
,      C.population -- <-- added
```

Comment: @user3651955: need more help?

Comment: Thank you for you ansewrs, i don't want to add C.population in group by

Comment: Then don't use the field in the `count`.

Comment: But in my  calculation I need to divide by the total population, "COUNT( NB_births_M+ NB_births_F)/C.population as  Birthrate"